# MaxDirectMemorySize usage

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

I'm using jdk1.8.0_92. My VM is like the below.

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

My jinfo for MaxDirectMemorySize is

```
$jinfo -flag MaxDirectMemorySize 41266
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=0
```

But i don't know how much direct memory will be allocated for that VM. Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `MaxDirectMemorySize` is not specified explicitly, the default limit will be equal to the heap size: `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` ([the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a71d26266469/src/share/classes/sun/misc/VM.java#l282)).